# Automatic `List`ing of variables defined in an object (scala)

Tags: scala

Consider the following program. There are a bunch of type definitions, and a trait, and an object extending this trait.

This is a very simplified version of my program. The type definitions and trait are inside the program, and *the user* is supposed fill out the details inside the object:

```
/* ---------------------------------------------------*/      
/** the internal program */ 
case class Type1()
case class Type2()
case class Type3()

trait aTrait {
   // some stuff here 
}
/* ---------------------------------------------------*/ 
/** user side */ 
object samepleObject extends aTrait {
  val object1 = new Type1()
  val object2 = new Type1()
  val object3 = new Type2()
  val object4 = new Type3()

  // list of all objects here
  // this definition should be populated automatically. 
  val all = List(object1, object2, object3, object4)
}
```

The user is supposed to define a set of variables (of possibly different types). There is a variable `all` which is a `List` of all variables user has defined. The question is it possible to define and populate this variable automatically (possibly inside the `aTrait` trait)?

Comment: What about other instances of classes TypeN created elsewhere? Or all they call created in the object?

Comment: Just this specific `object`. In fact the usage is limited. This is is the object which can extend the `aTrait `. So don't worry about anywhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This reminds me a bit of what `Enums`. I think you can only achieve something like that with a mutable state in your object or `aTrait`. That also means handlinf thread safety.

You could do something like

```
/* ---------------------------------------------------*/
/** the internal program */
case class Type1()
case class Type2()
case class Type3()

import scala.collection.mutable

trait aTrait {
 private[this] var registry = mutable.ListBuffer.empty[Value[_]]

  case class Value[T](value: T) {
    registry.synchronized { registry :+= this }
  }

  def all: List[Value[_]] = registry.toList
}
/* ---------------------------------------------------*/
/** user side */
object sampleObject extends aTrait {
  val object1 = Value(new Type1())
  val object2 = Value(new Type1())
  val object3 = Value(new Type2())
  val object4 = Value(new Type3())
}

val test = sampleObject.all

> test: List[sampleObject.Value[_]] = List(Value(Type1()), Value(Type1()), Value(Type2()), Value(Type3()))
```

However, I do not guarantee concurrency-issuelessness

Comment: The line `def all: List[Value[_]] = registry.toList` is evaluated when the program starts to run; right? If that's the case, since I am going to use the values inside `all` (and not add anything into it), it won't make any concurrency issues, I think.

Comment: @Daniel it should be ok for trivial applications. I might even be ok in more complex situations. I just wanted to point out, that you should keep thread safety in mind when using it.

Comment: Kolbeg is it possible to handle this with some sort of reflection technique?

Comment: it seems like java can handle these with reflection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857775/getting-a-list-of-accessible-methods-for-a-given-class-via-reflection