# What is the semantic of "declaring a method"?

Tags: jqassistant

Based on the query defined in metric.xml I try to figure out how many methods a class declares:

```
MATCH
    (t:Type:File)-[:DECLARES]->(m:Method)
WHERE 
    t.fqn=~'.*MyException'
RETURN
    t.fqn as Type, COUNT(m) as MethodCount
```

It's 41.

I change the query to

```
MATCH
    (t:Class:File)-[:DECLARES]->(m:Method)
WHERE
    t.fqn=~'.*MyException'
RETURN
    t.fqn as Type, COUNT(m) as MethodCount
```

and I get 25 for the same class. Shouldn't it be the same result?
If I open the class and count by hand, I find only 23. So what does it mean if a class or a type "declares" a method? It seems some inherited methods are counted too depending on :Type or :Class.  And how do I get the "real" number of methods declared by the class itself without inherited methods?

Comment: check this one out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857775/getting-a-list-of-accessible-methods-for-a-given-class-via-reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is that the same exception type very likely is available as multiple nodes because it is contained in one artifact and required by others. To find the "real" node use the following query:

```
MATCH
  (:Artifact)-[:CONTAINS]->(t:Type)-[:DECLARES]->(m:Method)
WHERE
  t.fqn=~'.*MyException'
RETURN
  t.fqn as Type, COUNT(m) as MethodCount
```

Comment: Also with this query I get two additional methods: getCause() and initCause(Throwable) from Throwable. Both methods were *called* from MyException, but not *declared* in it. These methods only have a signature property so that I'm able to filter now correctly, but perhaps a hint in the docs for metric.xml would be nice.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the exception calling these methods? I would like to have a look at the generated bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

The first query finds multiple type nodes with the same fqn and aggregates the result. Just add id(t) to the return clause and you should see it.

Answer (score 0):

There were several connected questions in the original post. The answer how to find only the methods really declared in a class is:

```
MATCH
  (:Artifact)-[:CONTAINS]->(t:Type)-[:DECLARES]->(m:Method)
WHERE
  t.fqn=~'.*MyException' AND m.name <> ''
RETURN
  t.fqn as Type, COUNT(m) as MethodCount
```